# retrieving custom list javascript

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, caml-query

This is my first attempt at this software and I'm having problems pulling data from a custom list I've created in sharePoint.

Here's what I have

```
    <script>

var items;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[name=ItemChildCount]").text("owlData");
         var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('owlData');
         var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
         items = list.getItems(camlQuery, 'owl');

         context.load(items);

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed));  
    });

    function onListDataSucceeded(sender, args) {

        var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();


        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            alert(oListItem.get_item('owl'));
        }

    }

    function onListDataFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('List Data fetch failed. ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    </script>
```

The custome list name is owlData (based on an online example)
columns are: owl, date, action, location

I'm just trying to grab data from the owl column (a starting point)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function getData(){
        //your code to get data from sharepoint list.  
    }, "sp.js");
 });
```

load sp.js and then your code to retrieve list data

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to specify your custom column in the request.

Replace:

```
context.load(items);
```

With:

```
context.load(items, 'Include(owl)');
```

Comment: I've tried and the script doesn't run passed the changed statement. originally I've put an echo statement in the "onListDataSucceeded" function, right before the alert statement in the while loop and it echos out a statement.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Developer Tools Console?

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from the custom SharePoint list you can use the `lists.asmx` webservice.

You can do something like this

```
  (function ($) {
//Get Elements from a custom list 
var ListName ="Custom ";    
var url = document.URL;
if (url.indexOf("https://") != -1) {
    var urllink = document.location.href.replace("https://", "");
    var prefix = "https://";
}
else {
    var urllink = document.location.href.replace("http://", "");
    var prefix = "http://";
}
var link;
if (urllink.indexOf("sites") != -1)
    link = (urllink.split("/"))[0] + "/" + (urllink.split("/"))[1] + "/" + (urllink.split("/"))[2];
else
    link = (urllink.split("/"))[0];
var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
        <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
        <listName>"+ ListName + "</listName> \
        </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
$.ajax({
    url: prefix + link + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: processResult,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});

//Process data from the list 
function processResult(xData, status) {      
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('ows_LinkTitle'))             
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```